# Obtener texto de una celda que tiene ID variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen dia, tengo la siguiente tabla definida en mi documento HTML

```
<table id="tabla_productos">
    <tr>
        <td">DESCRIPCION PRODUCTO</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

en donde despues de una consulta a MySql creo filas cada una con una celda de id=OP5 (siendo 5 el id del producto alla en mysql por ejemplo) con la informacion de los productos recibidos los cuales guardé en un JSON llamado respuesta[]... en la siguiente linea en un script

```
document.getElementById("tabla_productos").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = "<td id=OP"+idproducto" onclick=producto_escogido(this) >"+respuesta[x]+"</td>";
```

quedando por ejemplo mi tabla original con 3 filas mas que fueron los resultados de la consulta mySQL, ejemplo:

```
<table id="tabla_productos">
    <tr>
        <td>DESCRIPCION PRODUCTO</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td onclick=producto_escogido(this) id="OP8">MANZANA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td onclick=producto_escogido(this) id="OP12">PERA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td onclick=producto_escogido(this) id="OP18">BANANO</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

es decir la consulta arrojó el siguiente resultado

IDPRODUCTO   PRODUCTO
    8        MANZANA
    12       PERA
    18       BANANO

Hasta aqui todo de maravilla, solo lo explico para poner en contexto, lo que quiero es capturar el valor de la celda donde haga click, a cada TD le puse la funcion onclick=producto_escogido(this) en el cual se supone haré eso... aqui el codigo

```
producto_escogido(celda)
{     
   //aqui capturo el id de la celda donde di clic, funciona bien pues si hago un alert me muestra el id del td donde hice clic y se supone que debo usarlo mas abajo
   let producto_escogido=celda.id;

  //este codigo me hace un alert del texto de todas las celdas sin importar en cual di clic
  $('#tabla_productos td').each(function(){
    var cellText = $(this).html();
    alert("producto escogido: "+cellText);
  });
}
```

la pregunta es, que modifico en el codigo donde recorro los td para que solo me tome el valor del td donde di clic?

intenté con esto pero me da error

```
$('#tabla_productos td').each(function(){
    var cellText = $('#producto_escogido').html();
    alert("producto escogido: "+cellText);
});
```

alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Fue algo confuso pero veamos si entendi. Lo que quieres es que cuando presionen click sobre manzana se capture su valor.

tienes el siguiente valor en tu html:   `<td id="OP8">MANZANA</td>`

yo le agregaria un jquery. y antes no se te olvide agregar la libreria jquery en tu head  `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Lo haria de la siguiente forma

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.("#OP8").click(function(){
alert("Text: " + $("#OP8").text());

});
<script>
```